# Coverage Reports on SonarQube Preview/Incremental analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

We've recently set our Continuous Integration environment to do an incremental code analysis before a Merge Request on Git can be accepted. We already use the HTML issues report and the Build Breaker plugin. Everything works beautifully. The thing is, we're having some issues because the build is broken on < 85% code coverage. I didn't find any plugin to let the user know where the coverage dropped. Is there any way to show that comparison between the analisys that is recorded on my server and the one Jenkins is incrementally building ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using sonar4.5.4 and we use the Coverage on new code metric in our quality gate, in that metric we compare with the previous analysis

Comment: Awesome Ashokekumar S! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Right, but in a preview or incremental analysis, nothing is recorded in Sonar, so where can you see which particular files had poor coverage on new code?

Comment: If sonar has the property set to show the source code - then we can drill down at each file level and check the coverage